# Node.js server is stopping when something is logged into console

Tags: node.js

I am starting Node.js server on linux machine using `node server.js &` command.

but when something is logged onto console, the log appears and the server is stopped.

This problem isn't rising when I remove all `console.log()` statements

But, is there any way to prevent this, without removing `console.log()` statements?

Comment: Show us the contents of the server.js.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like perhaps you have an uncaught exception being thrown which node then is stopping from. You could catch those exceptions globally...

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
   console.log(error.stack);
});
```

Alternatively, you could look into using something like supervisor (https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) or forever (https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to keep your node app constantly running...

Comment: Your first example is dangerous, it should `process.exit();` in your `uncaughtException` handler, otherwise it could lead to unknown state in your application.  Only try/catch/resume on exceptions when you know *exactly* what is happening, around the smallest block of code you can manage.  If you want more control, try using domains.

Comment: Dangerous if deployed in a production environment. He is obviously just learning node and will learn things over time...

Comment: Fair enough, though I think it's worth it to at least plant the seed that there's more to this than what you see here.